# How do I combine these 2 SQL queries?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to combine data from from multiple table and send it to the blade template.

I tried to put `total_price` with `->select('products.name', total_price`, but I got

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column`

```php
$orders = DB::table('orders')
    ->join('order_items', 'order_items.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
    ->join('customers', 'customers.id', '=', 'orders.customer_id')
    ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'order_items.product_id')
    ->select('products.name', DB::raw('SUM(order_items.quantity * order_items.unit_price) as total, SUM(order_items.quantity) as quantity'))
    ->whereYear('orders.created_at', $currentYear)
    ->whereMonth('orders.created_at', $currentMonth)
    ->where('orders.customer_id', $id)
    ->groupBy('order_items.product_id');

$order_prices = DB::table('orders')->select('total_price')->get();
```

Comment: Laracast guide https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravels-groupby-not-working

Comment: You don't have `products.name` in the `GROUP BY`, so that's at least one thing at least.

Comment: Why are you not using models for this? Would make it much, much simpler to work with.